# Privacy page redirection in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

In my project I have a privacy policy form page. After login, though custom code I am redirecting to that page. When user check the  privacy policy, I will store the data in variable table.

What I need is if I click any page with out accepting the privacy policy, I need to again redirect to privacy page. I need to check this logic in every page load. Where I need to check this? Is it on hook_init(). When I given this in hook_init(), which is not working. Please see my below code.

```
$getAcc = variable_get('privacy_38');
if($getAcc  == 1) {
global $user;
$accessRedirection =  'privacy/accept'; 
$afterUserView = 'user/' . $user->uid . '/view';
$options = array('query' => array('destination' => $afterUserView));
drupal_goto($accessRedirection, $options
}
```

Where I need to put this code. Is it in theme template. If so, in which hook, I need to put this code. Please anybody help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's definitely the place to do it (hook_init), but will take a bit more than what you have to fully achieve what you need. There's a module that implements something very similar to this that you might want to have a look at if you haven't yet: https://www.drupal.org/project/legal

Hope this helps!

Comment: Alberto, I tried with hook_init(). But it goes infinite loop and shows the page isn't redirecting properly. Also I cannot use the legal module because I need some custom changes through the code.

Comment: Think you're probably getting the infinite loop because init is run on every page call, so you'll need to redirect to the privacy policy page only if that's not the current page already, otherwise you'll end up in the loop. You can use the current_path() function that Drupal provides to check your current path. Hope this helps.